# Exception: URL fetch failure on https://s3.amazonaws.com/text-datasets/imdb.npz: None -- [WinError 10060]

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, imdb

*Following is the code for text classification problem over the IMDB dataset. I am unable to run the code as it is showing the error given below. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.*

**CODE:**

```py
from keras.preprocessing import sequence

from keras.models import Sequential

from keras.layers import Dense, Embedding, Conv1D, GlobalMaxPooling1D

from keras.datasets import imdb

max_features = 5000

maxlen = 100

batch_size = 64

embedding_dims = 16

filters = 128

kernel_size = 3

epochs = 5


(x_train, y_train), (_, _) = imdb.load_data(num_words = max_features)


x_train = sequence.pad_sequences(x_train, maxlen = maxlen)

print(len(x_train))

for sample in x_train :

    print(sample)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Embedding(max_features, embedding_dims, input_length = maxlen))

model.add(Conv1D(filters, kernel_size, padding = 'valid', activation = 'relu', strides = 1))

model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())

model.add(Dense(128, activation = 'relu'))

model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['acc'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size = batch_size, epochs = epochs)
```

**ERROR :**

```
Downloading data from https://s3.amazonaws.com/text-datasets/imdb.npz

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)

   1316                 h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,

-> 1317                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))

   1318             except OSError as err: # timeout error


~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)

   1228         """Send a complete request to the server."""

-> 1229         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)

   1230 



~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)

   1274             body = _encode(body, 'body')

-> 1275         self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

   1276 



~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in endheaders(self, message_body, encode_chunked)

   1223             raise CannotSendHeader()

-> 1224         self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

   1225 


~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _send_output(self, message_body, encode_chunked)

   1015         del self._buffer[:]

-> 1016         self.send(msg)

   1017 


~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in send(self, data)

    955             if self.auto_open:

--> 956                 self.connect()

    957             else:



~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in connect(self)

   1383 

-> 1384             super().connect()

   1385 


~\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in connect(self)

    927         self.sock = self._create_connection(

--> 928             (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)

    929         self.sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)



~\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address)

    726     if err is not None:


--> 727         raise err

    728     else:



~\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address)

    715                 sock.bind(source_address)

--> 716             sock.connect(sa)

    717             # Break explicitly a reference cycle



TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly 

respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to 

respond



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:



URLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py in get_file(fname, origin, untar, md5_hash, 

file_hash, cache_subdir, hash_algorithm, extract, archive_format, cache_dir)

    221             try:

--> 222                 urlretrieve(origin, fpath, dl_progress)

    223             except HTTPError as e:



~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in urlretrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)

    246 

--> 247     with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:

    248         headers = fp.info()



~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)

    221         opener = _opener

--> 222     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)

    223 



~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)

    524 

--> 525         response = self._open(req, data)

    526 



~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in _open(self, req, data)

    542         result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +

--> 543                                   '_open', req)

    544         if result:



~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)

    502             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)

--> 503             result = func(*args)

    504             if result is not None:



~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in https_open(self, req)

   1359             return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,

-> 1360                 context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)

   1361 



~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)

   1318             except OSError as err: # timeout error

-> 1319                 raise URLError(err)

   1320             r = h.getresponse()



URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not 

properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has 

failed to respond>



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:



Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-16-82c1e9073098> in <module>

      8 epochs = 5

      9 

---> 10 (x_train, y_train), (_, _) = imdb.load_data(num_words = max_features)

     11 

     12 x_train = sequence.pad_sequences(x_train, maxlen = maxlen)



~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\datasets\imdb.py in load_data(path, num_words, skip_top, maxlen, 

seed, start_char, oov_char, index_from, **kwargs)

     55     path = get_file(path,

     56                     origin='https://s3.amazonaws.com/text-datasets/imdb.npz',

---> 57                     file_hash='599dadb1135973df5b59232a0e9a887c')

     58     with np.load(path) as f:

     59         x_train, labels_train = f['x_train'], f['y_train']



~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py in get_file(fname, origin, untar, md5_hash, 

file_hash, cache_subdir, hash_algorithm, extract, archive_format, cache_dir)

    224                 raise Exception(error_msg.format(origin, e.code, e.msg))

    225             except URLError as e:

--> 226                 raise Exception(error_msg.format(origin, e.errno, e.reason))

    227         except (Exception, KeyboardInterrupt):

    228             if os.path.exists(fpath):



Exception: URL fetch failure on https://s3.amazonaws.com/text-datasets/imdb.npz: None -- [WinError 10060]
```

A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time,

or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Answer (score 0):

Your network issue. Url https://s3.amazonaws.com/text-datasets/imdb.npz is accessible from other networks.

Comment: Code worked perfectly fine when I used Google colab. How can I resolve the problem with Anaconda and Pycharm ?

Comment: Try downloading the file manually and use it like: 
(x_train, y_train), (_, _) = imdb.load_data(path="imdb.npz",
                                                      num_words= max_features)